# show and hide button in php

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm working on side php project and I'm just wondering how can I modify my code so that there will be only one button instead of two.

Right now, I have show and hide buttons. I'm thinking about having only one button and it will display Hide option first. after a user click Hide option then it'll change it to show.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light" onClick="hide_div('transpose-keys');">Hide</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light" onClick="show_div('transpose-keys');">Show</button>
```

```
function hide_div(e) {
  $(".c").hide()
  $("."+e).hide()
}
function show_div(e) {
  $(".c").show()
  $("."+e).show()
}
```

Comment: Add a `display: none|block` css class and toggle it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why did you tag this question with PHP, but not share any related code? Also, is PHP even needed for this?

Comment: @medilies how do I toggle it, I would be really appreciated if  you can help me in more details thank.

Comment: [we too would like to have more details...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  the simplest solution would be to know the global element of all these objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to define a **CSS class to hide elements**, `{ display: none }`.
2. That class will be **injected** to the target element to hide it or **removed** to get it back to be displayed.

```js
setHiddable("hide-show", "target");

/**
 * Ideal to set a hide/show relationship between only two elements
 * @param {string} btnId The ID of the button that toggle the view
 * @param {string} elementId The ID of the element to be toggled
 */
function setHiddable(btnId, elementId) {
    const btn = document.querySelector(`#${btnId}`);

    // Listen to clicks
    btn.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
        const targetEl = document.querySelector(`#${elementId}`);
        // Hide if shown
        // Show if hidden
        targetEl.classList.toggle("hidden");
    });
}
```

```css
#target {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="target"> This is the element that you want to show and hide on click </div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="hide-show">TOGGLE VIEW</button>
```